# Is there a way to implement the IRR algorithm in PuLP?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp, irr

Numpy has a function which allows me to calculate the IRR of an array of floats. My problem is that I am trying to use it within a PuLP problem, and the array that I want to pass to the function is compossed of the variables of the problem. Here i

```
    problem = pulp.LpProblem("TIR_MINIMIZE", pulp.LpMaximize)
    price_ppa = pulp.LpVariable("price_ppa")
    price_production = []

    for i in range(10):
        price_production.append(price_ppa * annual_production[i])
        # anual_production is an array of values calculated outside the function

    irr = numpy.irr(price_production)

    # CONSTRAINTS #####################################################################################
    problem += irr>= 0.075

    objective_function = -irr
    problem += objective_function

    #####################################################################################################
    problem.solve()
```

And this code doesn't work because numpy.irr is expecting an array of floats, while I pass it an array of LpAffineExpressions. My question is, is there a way to implement this in a somewhat easy way? I have tried to implement the algorithm manually, but I can't do it inside the PuLP constraint definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theory

The IRR computation is inherently nonlinear, so this cannot be handled in a PuLP model. PuLP only deals with linear models.

Practice

You are calling `numpy.irr` but this must be called while the LP solver is running. That is not allowed. LP solvers cannot call external functions.